# Keilim Mikva design

Tags: halacha, tevilas-keilim-dipping, mikvah-ritual-bath, architecture-design

I live in a neighborhood where it is difficult to find a Keilim mikva. Are there any designs available for how to build one? Is it as hard to build as a human mikva?

Comment: Can't you use your local human _mikve_? ([CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR), of course, to be sure it's okay halachically, and the people who run the _mikve_ to be sure it's okay with them.)

Comment: it's hard to get to one :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possibility might just be to use a local pond or lake. (Rivers or streams are a possibility too, but there are more halachic issues with those, involving issues of how much groundwater vs. rainwater they contain.) Those generally aren't usable for human mikvaos because of the lack of privacy, but that wouldn't apply to dishes.

Answer (score 5):

[CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) regarding following [R' Dovid Miller's instructions](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=2920&st=&pgnum=379).  If I remember correcty, he allows the use of tap water through a rubber connection.  Nowadays, most do not rely on this, but may be lenient for rabbinic or keli use.

Comment: Particularly for glass keilim which all agree are derabanan.