# Could pipes from a boiler to a sink ever be considered a kli sheini?

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, appliances, meat-and-milk

A reason why having two sinks, in a kitchen, is justified, is because hot meat and milk cleaned or mixed together in a single sink could constitute bishul; one of the three prohibitions of "לֹא-תְבַשֵּׁל גְּדִי, בַּחֲלֵב אִמּוֹ" (Shemot 23:19, 34:26, Deut. 14:21)

The hot water that arrives at one's sink comes from a boiler, which flows through pipes before it reaches your sink. Are there any opinions that suggest that pipes containing water constitute a kli sheini? The ramification being, that there could be no prohibition of cleaning/mixing hot meaty and milky items in a sink together (for those that hold that there is no bishul in a kli sheini, even when it is above yad soledet boh).

Comment: You never pour hot water from a pot through a strainer?

Comment: bondonk, are you concerned that meat and milk residue will both simultaneously be submerged in water poured from a Kli Rishon?

Comment: @DoubleAA this could be considered a problem by many. However, I was wondering whether the issue of washing meat/milk items in a single sink is bypassed by pipes from a boiler possibly having kli sheini status.

Comment: @bondonk You asked about the prohibition on bishul though.

Answer (score 1):

See [this other Mi Yodea Question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31414/filling-a-mikvah-from-the-faucet) which cites a source that municipal tap water could be used to fill up a mikvah.

The reason for this is, pipes are not considered to be keilim.

Normative practice has become to build mikvaot with many stringencies, but the basic fact that a pipe does not have a "beit kibel" (receptacle) and therefore, is not a kli, is generally accepted.

Therefore, the pipe from the hot water heater to the sink isn't a kli, and the water that comes into a kitchen sink is water from a kli rishon.

Comment: When the sink is closed, isn't it a Beit Kibbul?

Comment: I think you are confusing a lot of different concepts.

Comment: the halachic definition of a receptacle is the same in mikvaot and bishul.  It's the same concept.